# how do I remove gaps between int values in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, command-line

Given a file containing two columns of integers, I want to get rid of the gaps between the integer values. By gap I mean that if we take two integers A and B, in a way that there is no C such as A

```
1 2
1 3
2 5
6 9
3 5
7 9
11 6
7 11
```

to this:

```
1 2 
1 3
2 4
5 7
3 4
6 7
8 5
6 8
```

In the first two columns, the present integers are {1,2,3,5,6,7,9,11}. The missing values are {4,8,10}. the goal is to decrease every integer by the number of missing values that are smaller than it.
so 5,6 and 7 are decreased by 1, 9 us decreased by 2, and 11 is decreased by 3.
so the values {1,2,3,5,6,7,9,11} are replaced by {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}.
does anyone know how to do it efficiently, using a linux command, a bash script or and awk command?
Thank you!

Edit:
I tried to do it but I didn't find a way to do it in a shell script, I had to write a c program which executes shell scripts.
the first part just sorts the file, the second, does what I talked about in the question.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


#define MAX_INTS 100000000

void process_file(char *path){
    //FIRST PART
    char *outfpath="tmpfile";
    char *command=calloc(456+3*strlen(path)+strlen(outfpath),sizeof(char));

    sprintf(command,"#!/bin/bash \nvar1=$( cat %s | head -n 4  && ( cat %s | tail -n +5  | awk '{split( $0, a, \" \" ); asort( a ); for( i = 1; i <= length(a); i++ ) printf( \"%c%c \", a[i] ); printf( \"\\n\" ); }' | sort -n -k1,1 -k2 | uniq) )\nvar2=$( ( (echo \"$var1\" | tail -n +5 | cut -f 1 -d\" \") && (echo \"$var1\" | tail -n +5 | cut -f 2 -d\" \" ) ) | sort -n -k1,1 | uniq | awk '{for(i=p+1; i<$1; i++) print i} {p=$1}' )\necho \"$var1\" > %s\necho \"$var2\"| tr \"\\n\" \" \" > %s",path,path,'%','s',path,outfpath);

    if(system(command)==-1){
        fprintf(stderr,"Erreur à l'exécution de la commande \n%s\n",command);
    }
    //the first part only sorts the file and puts in outpath the list of the missing integers

    //SECOND PART
    long unsigned start=0,end=0,val,index=0;
    long unsigned *intvals=calloc(MAX_INTS,sizeof(long unsigned));
    FILE *f=fopen(outfpath,"r");

    //reads the files and loads the missing ints to the array intvals
    while(fscanf(f,"%lu ",&val)==1){
        end=index;
        intvals[index]=val;
        index++;
    }
    if (index==0) return;
    intvals=realloc(intvals,index*sizeof(long unsigned));
    fclose(f);
    free(command);


    f=fopen(path,"r+w");
    char *line=calloc(1000,sizeof(char));
    command=calloc(1000,sizeof(char));
    char *str;
    long unsigned v1,v2,
        d1=0,d2=0,
        c=0,prec=-1,start_l=0;
    int pos1, pos2;  

    //read a file containing two columns of ints 
    //for each pair v1 v2, count d1 d2, 
    //such as d1 is the number of missing values smaller than v1, d2 the number of missing values smaller than v2
    //and overrwrite the line in the file using sed with the values v1-d1 and v2-d2

    while(fgets(line,1000,f)!=NULL && line[0]=='#'){ continue; }

    do{
        str=strtok(line," \t");
        v1=atoi(str);
        str=strtok(NULL," \t");
        v2=atoi(str);
        if(prec!=v1) {
            prec=v1;
            d2=d1;
            start_l=start;
        }
        for(index=start;index<=end;index++){ 
            if(intvals[index]<v1){ 
                 d1++; 
                 start++;
                 c=1;
            }else{
                start=d1;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(index=start_l;index<=end;index++){ 
            if(intvals[index]<v2){ 
                d2++; 
                start_l++;
                c=1; 
            }else{ 
                break;
            }
        }         
        if(c){
            sprintf(command,"sed -i 's/%lu %lu/%lu %lu/' %s",v1,v2,v1-d1,v2-d2,path);
            if(system(command)==-1){
                fprintf(stderr,"Erreur à l'exécution de la commande \n%s\n",command);
            }
        }
        c=0;
    }while(fgets(line,1000,f)!=NULL);
    fclose(f);
    free(command);
    free(line);
    free(intvals);
}



int main(int argc,char* argv[]){

    process_file(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @kvantour I see, but the thing is, it seems to me like something simple to do, I don't seem to find a way to do it efficiently, I added what I tried to do

Comment: @Inian I added what I tried, and the reason why it doesn't work is that it takes too long to execute 'cause I use sed to replace every line with the new values, the time complexity is n^2, and I'm looking for a way to do it more efficiently

Comment: I think my big question is - why? Are you trying to create a specific output? Then ignore this and just write that output. If what you are specifically trying to do is edit this file according to rules, then I'm not clearly understanding the rules.

Comment: @PaulHodges The integer values correspond to ids of nodes in an undirected graph, and the files are edgelists of those graphs, but since the graphs are edited over time, some nodes are deleted, some edges are added and deleted etc, I end up having gaps between the ids of the nodes and I want to get rid of those gaps. the ids are positive integers. What I do in the c program is write all the missing integers in the file between 0 and the biggest integer in the file. then read the file again the replace every integer with it's value minus the number of missing integers that are smaller than it.

Comment: Some good thoughts in the answers below. That you chose to call `sed` inside of this complex set of `c` code indicates you're not familiar with `awk`. It makes tasks such as yours able to process all inside one process and will reduce your run time significantly. With JohnBrown's solution, you can even use built in features to reduce your code base.  Not sure how your data works, but hopefully you are aware of the *nix utitilty `tsort` (topographic sort). It might be another good tool for your toolbox. Good luck!

Comment: Oh, and ++ for improving your Q by showing your code. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might do it:

```
awk '(NR==FNR){for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) {a[$i]; max=(max<$i?$i:max)};next}
     (FNR==1) {for(i=1;i<=max;++i) if(i in a) a[i]=++c }
     {for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) $i=a[$i]}1' file file
```

If `file` has as input:

```
1 2
1 3
2 5
6 9
3 5
7 9
11 6
7 11
```

The above command will return:

```
1 2
1 3
2 4
5 7
3 4
6 7
8 5
6 8
```

The idea of this method is to keep track of an array `a` which is indexed by the old value and returns the new value : `a[old]=new`. We scan the file twice and store all possible values in `a[old]`. When we read the file for the second time, we first check what the new values are going to be. When that is done, we just update all the fields with the new values and print the result.

The above can also be done by reading the file a single time, you just need to buffer a bit:

```
awk '{b[FNR]=$0;for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) {a[$i]; max=(max<$i?$i:max)}}
     END {
        for(i=1;i<=max;++i) if(i in a) a[i]=++c
        for(n=1;n<=FNR;++n) {
          $0=b[n]
          for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) $i=a[$i]
          print
        }
     }' file
```

Comment: Not me but I just tried it and it doesn't give the output requested: https://pastebin.com/LUYzMRcp

Comment: What does your file look like? (see my answer for what I have input)

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU awk and `asorti()`:

```
$ gawk '{                         # GNU awk only or implement sort
    a[$1];a[$2]                   # hash field values to a array
    f1[NR]=$1;f2[NR]=$2           # hash fields $1 and $2 index on NR
}
END {                             # after all data is hashed
    asorti(a,a,"@ind_num_asc")    # sort index of a where the values are
    for(i in a)                   # make a reverse map 
        b[a[i]]=i
    for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)            # iterate the stored "records"
        print b[f1[i]],b[f2[i]]   # print and fetch from reverse map
}' file
```

`a[]` stores the uniques field values: `a[6] a[5]` then `asorti()` re-indexes `a[]`: `a[1]=5 a[2]=6` and we get correponding new values. `b[]` is reverse mapping of `a[]`: `b[5]=1 b[6]=2` which is used to get new values for old field values when outputing.

Output:

```
1 2
1 3
2 4
5 7
3 4
6 7
8 5
6 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input looks like this:

input.txt

```
2 1
4 3
5 5
6 2
1 4
8 7
9 6
7 9
```

Note: No 3 in col1 and 8 in col2 just to make it easier to track.

Then sort each column individually and store it:

```
$sort -k1,1 input.txt | awk '{ print $1}'  > 1_sorted
$cat 1_sorted
1
2
4
5
6
7
8
9


$sort -k2,2 input.txt | awk '{ print $2}'  > 2_sorted
$cat 2_sorted
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
9
```

Now just merge the two files:

```
$paste -d' ' 1_sorted 2_sorted > merged_again

$ cat merged_again
1 1
2 2
4 3
5 4
6 5
7 6
8 7
9 9
```

There might be a more performant / elegant method but I can't think of it right now.

Comment: I think you did not understand my question, take a look at my example and my program please. the position of the values does not matter, what matters is that if we take any two different integers A and B where A>B and there is no integer C in the file such as C<A and C>B, then A-B=1. and to do that I list all the integers between the smallest and the biggest integer in the file, by missing I mean not present in the file. then for every integer in the file I decrease it's value by the number of missing integers that are smaller than it.

Comment: Clearly. I think @kvantour is the right solution for what you want then